# xwiki remove dashboard column

Tags: dashboard, xwiki

A simple question:

How do I remove a column from my xwiki dashboard?
I want only one column. There is a button for creating columns, but not for deleting it..

Regards,
Vince

Comment: I have it! ;)
If I move all Gadgets from the right side to the left, the second column will be removed automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no button for removing a column, but whenever the last column becomes empty, it will be automatically removed when saving.